# Como relacionar todo o workspace Javascript como Java?

Tags: javascript, java, atom

Eu quero ligar todos os arquivos javascript na minha IDE, como fazemos com Java no Eclipse. Eu estou tentando fazer isso no Atom ou VSCode. Algumas coisas que eu preciso:

- Eu quero vincular minha variáveis e funções globais, às vezes eu uso `require.js` mas às vezes eu adicionar todos os arquivos `.js` no `index.html`;
- Com `Ctrl + clique` (ou similar) eu quero ir para a implementação da variável/método (independente se esta no mesmo arquivo ou não);
- Ao usar `Ctrl + Space` (ou similar) depois de algum objeto por exemplo, eu quero ver todos os atributos dentro dele.

Isso é possível? Especialmente usando Atom ou VSCode?